# ¿Cómo cargo una imagen en Django con srcset?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms

Tengo la siguiente linea, la cual la estoy ejecutando en la carpeta **`template/home.html`**

```
<img src="{% static 'img/carpeta/portada.jpg' %}" srcset="img/carpeta/portada.jpg 1x, img/carpeta/portada@2x.jpg 2x'" alt="">
```

No logro cargar la imagen. El navegador envia un ***404 (Not Found)***

Alguna idea de como solucionarlo,he probado variar la posicion del ***static*** sin obtener cargar la imagen, alguna sugerencia

Comment: Hola, ¿cuál es tu estructura de archivos?, ¿cómo has definido los statics en tu settings.py?

Comment: Uso la siguiente static img/carpeta/portada.jpg, en lo que revise la direccion de estructura esta ok. Al añadir el SRCSET no me cargan esas imagenes. las otras que almaceno si funcionan